# Git merge conflict resolution: can I use strategy to automatically resolve some files?

Tags: git, git-merge

While git merging I run into a conflict. First file I want resolve manually but for other files I want to use `git merge my_branch -s ours`. How can I do that?

Comment: If you really want to ignore changes on the other side entirely, you can `git checkout HEAD <path>` for each such path.

Comment: If it's not required to do this via command line, some Git GUI apps (ex. SourceTree) already have this feature. You can view all the conflicted files, resolve some manually, then select all the rest and resolve them automatically by using "ours" or "theirs".

Comment: @Gino Mempin ty, didnt know that. Anyway, I want to do this in plain old git. :)